# converting 4D list to two 2D dictionary, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of 4dimension where list = `[( (1,2,3), 4, (0,2,3), 7) , ( (9,4,5), 10, (3,8,7), 15), .......]`. Total number of rows in list is 2000 (length). When I converted it to the two 2D dictionary in python by following code:-

```
for i in range(len(list)):
      if list[i] is not None:
         dic1[list[i][0]] = list[i][1]
         dic2[list[i][2]] = list[i][3]
```

finally after converting it to the two 2D dictionaries and checked length of two dict are different. `len(dic1) = 1660` and `len(dic2) = 1770`.

Why there is change in length of two dictionaries, But it should give equal length of two dict of length 2000?

Could anyone help i=me in getting the equal length 2D dictionaries of length (2000, )

Comment: Because some keys might clash... If you assign to key `(1,2,3)` twice **the last value** is retained.

Comment: because there are some key appearing again and again. Dictionary store only one same key. d = {"a":1, "a":2}`

Comment: What does 2D dictionary even mean?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at next example

```
some_dictionary = dict()
some_dictionary[(1, 2)] = 'a'
some_dictionary[(1, 2)] = 'b'
```

after all `some_dictionary` will have one key `(1, 2)` and its value will be `'b'`

If you need to collect different values for duplicate keys then you can use dictionary with list of values and then append each new value to them like

```
keys = [(1, 2), 'a', (1, 2), 'b']
values = ['3', [10, 15], 'text', True]
some_dictionary = dict()
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    some_dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

More info about `dict.setdefault` method at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, result is correct because there are some key appearing again and again and Dictionary store only one same key (i.e. overwrite previous value)

**Demo:**

```
>>> d = {"a":1, "a": 2}
>>> d
{'a': 2}
>>> d["a"] = 4
>>> d
{'a': 4}
```

---

You can use List of 2D data, then we will get same length of two list of 2D data.

**Demo:**

```
>>> list_4d = [( (1,2,3), 4, (0,2,3), 7) , ( (9,4,5), 10, (1,3,4), 8)]
>>> 
>>> list_2d_01 = []
>>> list_2d_02 = []
>>> 
>>> for item in list_4d:
...     list_2d_01.append([item[0], item[1]])
...     list_2d_02.append([item[2], item[3]])
... 
>>> print "Length of list_2d_01:", len(list_2d_01)
Length of list_2d_01: 2
>>> print "Length of list_2d_01:", len(list_2d_02)
Length of list_2d_01: 2
```

---

**Note:**

Do not use keyword as variable name.

`list` is keyword. Do not use as variable name.

**Demo:**

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
>>> list001 = list()
>>> list001
[]
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> list002 = list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```